american international and US layout
I all guys i just bought an Epomaker 75% layout keyboard. My problem is: if I set "american international" as default keyboard language i can press +e and i obtain "è" but i have to tap  +space bar to have only one `, otherwise i have to double tap the key
With US non international keyboard i can press only one time ` to obtain this. but i am completely unable to do the accents on vowelsw. Is this normal? It's difficult for me because im italian and i did not write never before now with 75% keyboard.

“Is it normal?” --> Yes it is.

Yes, this is normal. These are called "Dead Keys", and they either require to be followed by a letter where the dead key character goes above (" + a = ä, ` + e = è, ^ + i = î  etc.), or a space, to get the single/original character.
There is no solution on the US Int keyboard, as there are too few keys to have both the dead key and the normal key separately.

So the best is to set keyboard with International US and to get used with this layout by pressing the spacebar when i need only one apostrophe or quotation marks. Right?

Yes, I guess so. I’m on a german keyboard (T2), and have to press ^  + Space to get a ^, and + Space for. You get used to it.
)

"Best" is subjective but I would expect that an ISO physical layout, an Italian keycap set and corresponding settings would approach "best" closely for many Italians.
